# How to show deserialized TempData object in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm getting *System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'* error in Index2.cshtml file after deserializing my TempData object. How can I show my object without getting this error? ( This is my first time asking in here sorry if I made mistakes.)

```
  var products = new List<Products>
            {
                new Products {Id=56, ProductName="x",Quantity=45},
                new Products {Id=55, ProductName="y",Quantity=5},
                new Products {Id=54, ProductName="z",Quantity=4},
                new Products {Id=53, ProductName="t",Quantity=8},
                new Products {Id=52, ProductName="k",Quantity=12}
            };
         
            string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(products);
            TempData["products"] = data;
            return RedirectToAction("Index2");

 public IActionResult Index2()
        {
            var data = TempData["products"].ToString();
            List<Products> products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Products>>(data);
            
        return View();
        }

**Index2.cshtml**
<ul>
    @foreach(var item in TempData["products"] as List<Products>)
    {
                <li>@item.ProductName</li>
            }
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @ıremk, you use `JsonSerializer.Serialize(products);`, it seems contains in System.Text.Json package which is in asp.net core instead of asp.net, right?

Comment: If you use asp.net, which package is used for `JsonSerializer`? I think you mean .NET 5/.NET 6 which target framework is .net core.

Comment: I'm sorry it is asp.net core, I'm currently learning so I'm a newbie.

Comment: Hi @@ıremk, I have tested your code and reproduce your issue. Your problems caused by you do not set the deserialized model to TempData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
List<Products> products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Products>>(data);
```

To:

```
TempData["products"] = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Products>>(data);
```

Or you can use `return View(products)` to use the data:

```
public IActionResult Index2()
{
    var data = TempData["products"].ToString();
    List<Products> products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Products>>(data);

    return View(products);
}
```

View:

```
@model List<Products>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@item.ProductName</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: It worked thank you so much. I'm following a tutorial and they used List<Products> products  instead of TempData["products"] . Could you please tell me why we needed to change the code ?

Comment: Firstly, pls see your code, you just convert TempData to string, you even do not use the deserialize code(`List<Products> products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Products>>(data);`) to do anything. So your TempData is still a string, how can it auto serialize to a model in View.  Another way, if you want to use your deserialize code, you can use `return View(products)` and use `@model List<Products>` in your View. I will update my answer later.

Comment: I get it now, thanks again.